How can I link ADF to a MySQL DB
I'm trying to create a service linked to a MySQL DB. The issue I have is that MySSQL is expecting an SSH key, but using the connected service for MySQL does not give an option to enter SSH details. Normally in code, I'd supply localhost as well as the SSH file/key.

How can I add SSH details to the connection?
I need a Linked service to an MySql DB, The MySql is configured to use SSH. Setting the linked service up as below and pressing 'Test Connection', I receive a timeout and only assume it's because I've not passed an SSH Key.
If I was writing an Azure Function, I'd connect in the following way:
    var server = "server ip for MySQL";
    var sshUserName = "sshusernameHere";
    var sshPassword = "sshpasswordhere";
    var databaseUserName = "mysqldatabaseuser";
    var databasePassword = "mysqldatabasepassword";

    var (sshClient, localPort) = ConnectSsh(server, sshUserName, sshPassword, "path to my ssh key file");
    using (sshClient)
    {
        MySqlConnectionStringBuilder csb = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder
        {
            Server = "127.0.0.1",
            Port = localPort,
            UserID = databaseUserName,
            Password = databasePassword,
            Database = "databasename"
        };

Where ConnectSsh is:
public static (SshClient SshClient, uint Port) ConnectSsh(string sshHostName, string sshUserName, string sshPassword = null,
string sshKeyFile = null, string sshPassPhrase = null, int sshPort = 22, string databaseServer = "localhost", int databasePort = 3306)
{
    // check arguments
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sshHostName))
        throw new ArgumentException($"{nameof(sshHostName)} must be specified.", nameof(sshHostName));
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sshHostName))
        throw new ArgumentException($"{nameof(sshUserName)} must be specified.", nameof(sshUserName));
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sshPassword) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(sshKeyFile))
        throw new ArgumentException($"One of {nameof(sshPassword)} and {nameof(sshKeyFile)} must be specified.");
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(databaseServer))
        throw new ArgumentException($"{nameof(databaseServer)} must be specified.", nameof(databaseServer));

    // define the authentication methods to use (in order)
    var authenticationMethods = new List<AuthenticationMethod>();
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sshKeyFile))
    {
        authenticationMethods.Add(new PrivateKeyAuthenticationMethod(sshUserName,
            new PrivateKeyFile(sshKeyFile, string.IsNullOrEmpty(sshPassPhrase) ? null : sshPassPhrase)));
    }
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sshPassword))
    {
        authenticationMethods.Add(new PasswordAuthenticationMethod(sshUserName, sshPassword));
    }

    // connect to the SSH server
    var sshClient = new SshClient(new ConnectionInfo(sshHostName, sshPort, sshUserName, authenticationMethods.ToArray()));
    sshClient.Connect();

    // forward a local port to the database server and port, using the SSH server
    var forwardedPort = new ForwardedPortLocal("127.0.0.1", databaseServer, (uint)databasePort);
    sshClient.AddForwardedPort(forwardedPort);
    forwardedPort.Start();

    return (sshClient, forwardedPort.BoundPort);
}


You're going to need to elaborate on your assertion that "MySql is expecting an SSH key". I'm not familiar with any authentication method available in MySQL that relies on SSH keys.

Does your MySQL db belongs to azure? and provide the error details?

@esqew MySQL supports authentication by TLS certificate. We used this at my last job in lieu of passwords. In the CREATE USER, you can define the user auth requiring an X509 certificate, optionally require a specific issuer or subject. This means the client must specify a TSL certificate.  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.4/en/create-user.html

@esqew I have expanded my question to include how I would connect within an Azure Function. The Azure Function works and connects through, but I need to do this via the ADF built in functions and am not allowed to use my own function.

You seem to be creating an SSH tunnel and connect to mysql through that tunnel. I don't think this is a mysql question - it is a question if ADF supports SSH tunnelling for any of the connections.

@bilpor provide the error details of linked service?

@BillKarwin SSL and SSH are not entirely the same! I don't think this question is about authentication, but network access.

You are using Auto resolved Integration runtime  and enabled Not use system trust store, while connecting to SSH enabled on-premises MySQL database using MySQL linked service. That may be the reason to get error while testing the linked service. To resolve the error, you can follow below procedure:
Configure Self Hosted Integration Runtime, use it in linked service, and enable Use system trust store and provide required details in linked service as shown below:

Then you will be able to test the linked service successfully as shown below:

For more information you can refer to this.

when making a new integration runtime, both options to install the integration runtime wants to install on my local computer, but when all the ADF is set up, it will not be running from my local machine. So am I correct in assuming that I need to do this bit from the Server that will be running the ADF services

Does your IR status online? If your MySQL server is on-premises, IR should connect successfully.

MySQL is on-prem, but not on the same machine that I am using to develop with. If I ignore the 2 options, and just press apply, the status says unavailable.

Ensure you configured SHIR as in the provided document above and check the reference link which I provided at the last of my answer.
